# C++ Reading Whole Binary File into char array

Tags: c++, file, casting, buffer-overflow

I need to read the whole content of a binary file and pass it to my method that receives as input a char array. I have a doubt about casting:

```
infile.open(argv[1], std::ios::binary);
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
size_t file_size_in_byte = infile.tellg();
std::vector<char> data;
data.resize(file_size_in_byte);
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
infile.read(&data[0], file_size_in_byte);
```

How can I cast the vector to a char array now without having security memory errors?

Answer (score 1):

`&data[0]` is actually your cast. As long as your vector doesn't go out of scope, you don't free that pointer don't go past `file_size_in_byte` / `data.size()`. you can safely read through it. like:

```cpp
char* data_ptr = &data[0];

for(int i = 0; i < file_size_in_byte; i++)
{
   // do something with data_ptr[i]
}
```

or pass it to a function as in:

```cpp
char* data_ptr = &data[0];

process_file_data(data_ptr, data.size());
```

Or, as grizzly mentioned on the comment below, simply use: `char * data_ptr  = data.data();`

Comment: Or `char * data_ptr  = data.data();`

Comment: That is very true